# Sending hidden form with Javascript from one Wordpress custom page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am working with Wordpress, and I have two different custom pages, `page-A` and `page-B`.

On `page-A` I create a hidden form with Javascript, and submit it to `page-B`. This is my Javascript code on `page-A`:

```
function createFormAndSubmit(targetUrl, parameter) {
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.method = "POST";
    form.action = targetUrl;
    form.target = "_blank";
    var element1 = document.createElement("INPUT");
    element1.name="my_text"
    element1.value = parameter;
    element1.type = 'hidden';
    form.submit();
}

url = "<?= get_page_link(115) ?>";
parameterValue = evento.texto;

createFormAndSubmit(url, parameterValue);
```

As expected, a new tab opens up showing `page-B`. However, `page-B` doesn't seem to receive the parameter that I sent to it ("my_text") by submitting the hidden form. I do `print_r($_POST);` and just get an empty array.

Any ideas why I don't receive any parameters on `page-B`?

Note: I am intentionally not using JQuery. In stead we are using Angularjs.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to append the hidden element to the form.